# Type out X(squared) in Xcode TextField

Tags: xcode, textfield

I know that is confusing but I need a way for the user to be able to type out X and then (2 or (what ever letter)), but where it looks like the math problem X^2. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

```
@"\u2070 \u00B9 \u00B2 \u00B3 \u2074 \u2075 \u2076 \u2077 \u2078 \u2079"
```

0 - 9 respectively, except 1 2 and 3 are a little larger.

You need to replace your superscript characters with these codes.

Comment: So what if you want to do x to the power of 20?